# How to deploy an application in GKE from a public CI server

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy an application in a GKE 1.6.2 cluster running ContainerOS but the instructions on the website / k8s are not accurate anymore.

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): User "circleci@gophers-slack-bot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
cannot get deployments.extensions in the namespace "gopher-slack-bot".:
"No policy matched.\nRequired \"container.deployments.get\" permission." 
(get deployments.extensions gopher-slack-bot)
```

The repository for the application is available here [available here](https://github.com/gopheracademy/gopher).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a few breaking changes in the past with using the gcloud tool to authenticate kubectl to a cluster, so I ended up figuring out how to auth kubectl to a specific namespace independent of GKE. Here's what works for me:

On CircleCI:

```
setup_kubectl() {
echo "$KUBE_CA_PEM" | base64 --decode > kube_ca.pem
kubectl config set-cluster default-cluster --server=$KUBE_URL --certificate-authority="$(pwd)/kube_ca.pem"
kubectl config set-credentials default-admin --token=$KUBE_TOKEN
kubectl config set-context default-system --cluster=default-cluster --user=default-admin --namespace default
kubectl config use-context default-system
}
```

And here's how I get each of those env vars from kubectl.

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts $namespace -o json
```

The service account will contain the name of it's secret. In my case, with the default namespace, it's

```
"secrets": [
    {
        "name": "default-token-655ls"
    }
]
```

Using the name, I get the contents of the secret

```
kubectl get secrets $secret_name -o json
```

The secret will contain `ca.crt` and `token` fields, which match the `$KUBE_CA_PEM` and `$KUBE_TOKEN` in the shell script above.

Finally, use `kubectl cluster-info` to get the `$KUBE_URL` value.

Once you run `setup_kubectl` on CI, your `kubectl` utility will be authenticated to the namespace you're deploying to.

Comment: This solved it out. I'm sure there's more reading to it, like @aronchick pointed out, but for now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had to add the "Kubernetes Engine Admin" permission to my service user to allow kubectl to get this; otherwise => No policy matched.\nRequired \"container.secrets.get\" permission."

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes 1.6 and GKE, we introduce role based cess control. The authors of your took need to give the service account the ability to get deployments (along with probably quite a few others) to its account creation.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/